# Locate original location of installer exe on disk from within the installer c#

Tags: c#, windows-installer, working-directory

I have an MSI installer with a c# custom action running at the end that executes an sql script before the installer exits. We decided the best way to do this is to stick the sql script file in the same directory as the MSI file and have it load the script that way.

The problem is, the installer copies itself to Windows\system32 and then executes from there, so I cannot find the original directory in order to execute the script file. Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you copying an installer into a system folder?

Comment: I'm not. It's doing it itself. Or at least that's what it seems to be doing. When I write out the Directory.CurrentDirectory it shows Windows/system32 even though I'm launching it from some random place on my HD. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: @itslittlejohn Windows Installer always caches the installation package. It is required for uninstall, for example, where the original package is not available any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [`OriginalDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370562.aspx) property help you?

> The Windows Installer sets the **OriginalDatabase** property to the path of the installation database used to launch the installation. If the installation is launched from a command line, the value depends on whether the recache package option (the -v flag) is present in the **REINSTALLMODE** property.

Comment: The installer will be launched from another setup file. Does that count as from the command line? It looks like it should work for me though. I'll try it on Monday.

Comment: @itslittlejohn I guess they talk about different syntax: `msiexec /i product.msi` is the first case; `msiexec /x {PRODUCT-GUID}` is the second case. The first case corresponds to the action that is performed when you double-click .msi file in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Do you know what the second case refers to? It may not matter, but I don't know how to tell which case is being used. Both the setup and the msi are being generated by the installer project build.

Comment: @itslittlejohn The first case is *installation*. When the product is already installed, calling it `msiexec /i product.msi` usually shows you Modify, Repair, Remove options. Then Add/Remove Programs uses the product GUID to uninstall it, or modify/repair. In this case Windows Installer converts the GUID to the path of the cached .msi package; there will be no additional supporting files near the cached package — it's the 3rd case in OriginalDatabase property description. And the 2nd case is when you run a Repair and want to recache the original package by using -v flag.

Comment: See [MSI command line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988.aspx), the `/f` flag and its `v` option. If `v` presents when you run Repair, then you would (definitely) run the Repair operation from source, and `OriginalDatabase` property would point to the source package. Otherwise it points to the cached copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing managed custom actions in C# you should be using Windows Installer XML's (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).   You can create a C# project and add your SQL file as project content and it will get packaged up along for the ride and be available in the current directory at runtime.

BTW, assuming ( or not ) that you are using MSSQL, WiX already has SQL script execution handling.

Comment: We decided to go with the setup project for this one because its not that complex. In the future, it looks like WiX is a great solution though. The problem with adding the script at runtime (which would be simple in either case) is the script is different depending on the client. So we want to be able to drop it in manually when we give them the installer.

Comment: DTF CA's are basically C++ DLL's so you can still use them with setup projects.  You might also want to consider moving this from the installer and into the application as part of the first run.

Comment: I've already done that with a few scripts, but the reason we decided not to for this particular one is because it is different for each install and not always necessary. So this adds flexibility. Thanks for the advice though!